# Read PDF files in Universal App using C# and XAML , XAML error the resource itemsViewSource" could not be resolved?

Tags: c#, xaml

[image]

i'm trying to read PDF files with XAML and I 'm using the following controls 
but it says BooleanToVisibilityConverter not found and it's already add 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot see the image, usually do not worry about the designer but can you paste the code of Page.Resources? and the converter?

Comment: this is the Page.Resources<Page.Resources>
        <common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="itemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Items}"
            d:Source="{Binding Groups[0].Items, Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

Comment: Can you paste in the question the XAML to have better format, because I think I see an space in xmlns:common

Comment: it's  xmlns:common="using:MadeYour_Day.Common" ( _ ) and it's right i really can't understand why it's says (Error 1 The name "BooleanToVisibilityConverter" does not exist in the namespace "using:MadeYour_Day.Common")

Comment: Does it compile? Watch the output window forget the error

Comment: no it's doesn't compile this error make everything stop i had copy this code from this link please try to check it https://github.com/dotnetcurry/winrt-81-read-pdf

Comment: I need to see the full code of the Converter including the namespace, and is it in the same project?

Comment: i already solved the problem and it's run but it have exception ... i added try and catch but the area that allow me make browse it not work and this is the piece of code private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var sampleDataGroups = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupsAsync();
                this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = sampleDataGroups;
            }
            catch {
            
            }
        }

Comment: and this to select the pdf file  SampleDataGroup group = (SampleDataGroup)e.ClickedItem;
            StorageFile file = null;
            if (group.FileName == "Open File")
            {
                FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
                filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".pdf");
                filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
                filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
                filePicker.SettingsIdentifier = "picker1";

Comment: the remain of code as i can't post it all in comments as is exceed limits  filePicker.CommitButtonText = "Open Pdf File";

                file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                //var groupId = ((SampleDataGroup)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
                // TODO: Implement MRU functionality
            }
            if (file != null)
            {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SplitPage), file);
            }
        }  hope you can help me

Comment: Would you please edit the question instead of comments, it is hard to read all this